# posting a parameter to a jquery dialog box

Tags: php, jquery

i have a small problem
well i'm using a jquery dialog box, and i want to post a parameter to this dialog box

this is how i'm using it :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dialogShare").dialog({
                    resizable: true,
                    width:400,
                    modal: true,
                    autoOpen: false 
        });
});

$("#share").click(function(){
    $.post( 
            "/accueil.php",
            { name: $("#idPubToPreview").val() }
    );
    $("#dialogShare").dialog('open');
});
```

in the div that display the content of the dialog box "#dialogShare" i do a var_dump of $_POST but it seems to be empty !

any help please ?

Comment: Do you get any javascript console errors?

Comment: You need to be sure if the data has been sended like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f5mzq/).

Answer (score 1):

Place your click event within the document ready call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dialogShare").dialog({
        resizable: true,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $("#share").click(function() {
        $.post("/accueil.php", {
            name: $("#idPubToPreview").val()
        });
        $("#dialogShare").dialog('open');
    });
});​
```

Comment: no i have no error in the consol and i have already tried to put the hole code in the document ready but the the request is still empty